# run script when postfix/dovecot get new mail

Tags: bash, email, postfix-mta, dovecot

I have:

```
postfix->dovecot-> new mail go to [aaaa@11111.xemple.com] mailbox 
postfix->dovecot-> new mail go to [aaaa@22222.xemple.com] mailbox 
postfix->dovecot-> new mail go to [aaaa@33333.xemple.com] mailbox
```

I need run script when incoming mail comes and be saved by dovecot for domain 22222.xemple.com

**how to make when the new email comes to aaaa@22222.xemple.com dovecot run script:
sh /my/script/run/after/new/email/in/22222_xemple_com/run.sh**

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is server configuration. Try superuser or serverfault.

Comment: Show your code and more log examples.

Answer (score 3):

Use postfix transport!

1. add the user who will be run the command **transpostfix**
2. add to master.cf new transport:

   ```
   emailtransport   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
       flags=X user=transpostfix  size=26214400 argv=/my/script/run/after/new/email/in/22222_xemple_com/run.sh
   ```
3. add to main.cf link to transport file

   ```
   transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
   ```
4. edit transport file and run postmap

   ```
   #   postmap /etc/postfix/transport
   transpostfix@localhost.localhost    emailtransport:
   ```
5. add BCC. One mail go to Dovecot, second the same mail go to script. Edit
   in main.cf:

   ```
   recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps
   ```
6. /etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps

   ```
   ###    postmap /etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps
   aaaa@11111.xemple.com run_script@example.commm
   ```
7. add in main.cf options `virtual_alias_maps`
   and redirect mail from run_script@example.commm goto transpostfix@localhost.localhost

Answer (score 1):

With dovecot you can use pigeonhole.

Here is the official link for dovecot:
https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Plugins/Extprograms

it works together with the sieve server for filtering the mails so you can easily select which mails should be sent to your script.

Have fun
Wim

Answer (score 0):

use **incron**

/var/spool/incron:

```
/var/vmail/22222.xemple.com/aaaa/new IN_MOVED_TO,IN_ONESHOT /sys_my/postfix-mail/checker_postfix-parser.sh
```

**--------------------- stop read! older solution is not good ----**
I use ather programs for do it https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki#info

server: centos 6

script *postfix-parser.sh* to test if new letter comes to folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
###
### sh /sys_my/postfix-mail/postfix-parser.sh
while ((i<=END)); do
EVENT=$(inotifywait --format '%e' /var/vmail/22222.xemple.com/aaaa/new)
if [ "$EVENT" == "CREATE" ]; then 
echo $EVENT 
let ii++
echo $ii
fi
done
```

script *checker_postfix-parser.sh* to check if script run:

```
#!/bin/bash
###
# sh /sys_my/postfix-mail/checker_postfix-parser.sh

result=`ps aux | grep -i "postfix-parser.sh" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`
if [ $result -ge 1 ]
   then
        echo "script is running"
   else
    sh /sys_my/postfix-mail/postfix-parser.sh
fi
```

add to startup:
add this line:

```
sh /sys_my/postfix-mail/checker_postfix-parser.sh
```

to file:

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

run checker in cron every 5 min:

```
*/1 * * * * root sh /sys_my/postfix-mail/checker_postfix-parser.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the configuring of Dovecot to be a more elegant solution (as opposed to configuring Postfix) as @Wim suggests.  The steps are as follows:

1. create your script (ie. `mail_processor.py`) in the `/usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-execute/` directory:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python3
   from sys import stdin
   with open('/var/log/mail_processor.log', 'a') as logfile:
       for line in stdin:
           print(line.rstrip(), file=logfile)
   ```

   - ensure your script and target files have correct permissions:

     ```
     $ chmod +rx /usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-execute/mail_processor.py
     $ chmod 0777 /var/log/mail_processor.log
     ```
2. enable the `sieve_extprograms` plugin:

   - modify `\etc\dovecot\conf.d\90-sieve.conf`'s plugin section with the following:

     ```
     sieve_extensions = +vnd.dovecot.execute
     sieve_plugins = sieve_extprograms
     sieve_execute_bin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-execute
     ```
   - reload dovecot:

     ```
     $ service dovecot restart
     ```
3. create sieve filter (ie. in Roundcube goto `settings` -> `filters` -> `actions` -> `edit filter set`):

   ```
   require ["vnd.dovecot.execute"];
   # rule:[mail processing]
   if true
   {
       execute :pipe "mail_processor.py";
   }
   ```

Now all mail delivered to any mailbox with this sieve filter will be piped through `mail_processor.py` for action.

[Pigeonhole Sieve: Extprograms Plugin](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/sieve/plugins/extprograms/) documentation for reference